# c# search textbox keyword using SqlCommand in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql

I want to search all data in my `DataGridView`.

```
ID   Name           Effect
1   NameA   Release 
2   NameB   Make Stronger
3   NameC   Boost
```

In order to display proper data on DataGridView,

```
SqlCommand searchSqlCmmd;
SqlDataAdapter searchSqlAdpt;
DataTable searchDtbl = new DataTable();
searchSqlCmmd = new SqlCommand();
searchSqlCmmd.Connection = connection;
searchSqlCmmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
searchSqlCmmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM db.Ability WHERE Name = @searchText OR Effect = @searchText";
searchSqlCmmd.Parameters.Add("@searchText", TextBox.Text);
searchSqlAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(searchSqlCmmd);
searchSqlAdpt.Fill(searchDtbl);
uxTable.DataSource = searchDtbl;
TextBox.Clear();
```

For query string, I used `OR` that I think it will search both columns. However, it only searches first column(NAME). Is my query string (`CommandText`) wrong?

Comment: the `=` operator searches for an exact match. I guess you would like to look for contained words?=!  for that you would need to use `LIKE` and the wildcard `%` : `Effect LIKE %@searchText%`

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
SELECT * FROM db.Ability WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @searchText + '%' OR Effect = '%' + @searchText + '%'
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for something more like:

<s>"SELECT * FROM db.Ability WHERE Name LIKE %@searchText% OR Effect LIKE %@searchText%";</s>

EDIT:

You would want to use something like below

```
SELECT Name, Effect FROM datainfo
WHERE  Name LIKE '%Delta%' OR Effect LIKE '%Delta%';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c30bc5/3

Comment: @Sak, you're right. Thanks! I created a sqlfiddle to show a working example.